# can I integrate anylogic with a .net application

Tags: .net, integration, simulation, anylogic

1. can I integrate any logic simulation software  with a .net application?
2. I am trying the free version.Could anyone please help?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "integrate", there are a million ways here. AnyLogicis Java-based so I recommend first search for "integrate Java with .NET" to learn more on that front

Comment: just wanted to know if they are api's available that can be used in a .net application

Answer (score 0):

I have not ever seen an API for the AnyLogic PLE version, but for the paid version here are an API docs for manipulating the model parameters and objects, which are stored in AnyLogic Cloud: https://cloud.anylogic.com/files/api-8.5.0/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use network communication between the running simulation model and your .NET process. For instance, if the simulation needs to call the .NET process to retrieve some decision, you can use gRPC and create a java client and a .NET server. With gRPC you describe your messages as so called protocol buffers. Another possibility is to use message queuing frameworks such as ZeroMQ. Thereby you can implement different communication patterns including client/server, but also publish/subscribe.